# Using Blackberry to access an Oracle Database?

Tags: java, database, oracle, blackberry

I really hope would know how to do this cause I'm a total newbie to Blackberry development.

Basically, I was asked to write a brief report on how a blackberry would access a DB server like Oracle, and I don't know how a blackberry works well enough to figure this out. I tried searches for blackberry DB on Google and I always end up with blackberry viewer plus app for $39.99.. which is really annoying.

If anyone has done this or now how to point me to any good articles or tutorials or some code that explains how this would work that'd be awesome!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you need access to an application which backend runs on Oracle, the best thing you can do is access your database through an Application Server (Java, PHP, .NET).

This way, you communicate with your Database through a common application level protocol like HTTP, SOAP/HTTP, or whatever you can use natively on your Blackberry device. You don't need to provide your device with direct communication with the Oracle database which not only is easier but more secure.

Since you code your Blackberry apps in Java, you can be positive that you will have plenty support to do HTTP request and process its responses in your application.

Your Application will communicate with Oracle with its native protocol probably through a driver (JDBC, ADO.NET, PHP's oci wrapper) depending on the technology you pick.

Answer (score 6):

Everything Pablo said and some links ->

[blackberry.com/eng/developers](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/) - Start to understand Blackberry Development

[J2EE on Blackberry](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/started/develop/javaee.jsp) - Beginning J2ee on Blackberry

http://wbw-adc.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/bors-adfmobile.html - Really good overview By Oracle on them and Blackberry.

Comment: Awesome Thanks, I'll post a link to my report when I finish it.